# How to apply the Multiplication Rule of Probability?

Tags: probability

When we try to apply the multiplication rule of probability then we go as this:
Let E and F be two events associated with a sample space S. the set E ∩ F or EF
denotes the event that both E and F have occurred.we need to find the probability of the event EF.

For example, in the experiment of drawing two cards one after the other, we may be interested in finding the probability of the event ‘a king and a queen’. then to find this probability we find the product probability of drawing a king and conditional probability of drawing a queen from 52 cards given that a king card is drawn.

But as it is mentioned above E and F are events associated with the same sample space and the definition of event is that it is a subset of S.

Now in the above example the random experiment is drawing two cards one after the other without replacement i.e the sample space will be like {AA , KQ, QQ, ...} where A stands for ace, K for king etc. i.e it will have outcomes as an ordered pair but while finding conditional probability we take the event only as drawing either the first or the second card then how can we say that this is an event of the same random experiment? Can someone explain in detail?

Comment: Events are called independent if $P(A\cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$, [it yields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29) $P(A) = P(A|B)$ for conditional probabilities. In the _second_ experiment we are taking cards (sampling) _with_ replacement, so the set of cards is the same when you draw the second card and the same is the probability. You can manually compute all the probabilities by either combinatorics of by writing down all possible combinations to find that the formula for independent events works here.

Comment: "how can we say that this is an event of the same random experiment?" The events are *subsets* of the whole sample space. So looking at the described sample space with ordered pairs like $KA$ the event of drawing a king as first card is the set $\{K2,K3,\dots,KA\}$. The event of drawing first a king and then a queen is the singleton $\{KQ\}$.

Comment: @drhab then if the event of drawing king card is as you say it is then probability of this event will be 52/(52x52) but it should be 4/52.

Comment: The probability of drawing a king as first card is $P(\{K2\})+\cdots P(\{KA\})$ . This with $P(\{KK\})=\frac4{52}\frac3{51}$ and $P(\{K2\}=\cdots=P(\{KA\})=\frac4{52}\frac4{51}$ (exception for $KK$). Summation gives $\frac4{52}$. There are easier ways to calculate this, though.

Comment: @drhab So basically what we usually do or see in books is a simplified version of what you did here and can you tell the easier ways for this?

Comment: Easier with e.g. symmetry: the probability that the king is drawn as first card is the same as the probability that e.g. $5$ is drawn as first card. The event $K\cdot$ etc. are disjoint and cover the whole sample space, so $1=P(2\cdot)+\cdots+P(K\cdot)+P(A\cdot)$ with equal terms. Then $P(K\cdot)=\frac1{13}$

Answer (score 1):

There is no "multiplication rule" at work here, since there are no independent events belonging to the same sample space in sight.

Since you draw two cards without replacement from a deck $D$ consisting of $52$ cards you are picking a "random" $2$-element subset  of  $D$. The set of all these $2$-element subsets of $D$ is your sample space. The underlying model is that all ${52\choose2}$ such $2$-element subsets are equiprobable. How many of these  subsets contain a queen and a king? There are exactly $4\cdot4$ good choices, corresponding to a queen of one of the four suits and a king of one of the four suits. The probability of drawing exactly one queen and one king therefore comes to
$${16\over{52\choose 2}}={8\over663}\doteq0.0120664\ .$$